# Область видимости переменной в обработчике ajax

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю, в чем проблема и как исправить её.

Ниже приведен код для ajax.

```
   function artAjaxRequest(pageSrc)
    {
        var artworks;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/artworks/artworks.json', true);
        xhr.send();

        xhr.onload = function(){
            artworks = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log('artworks: ' + artworks); // выводит объект
        };

        return function()
        {
            console.log('artworks: ' + artworks); // выводит undefinded
        };
    }
```

Как я понимаю оно должно работать:

1. Создаю переменную: `getArtsThroughRequest =
   artAjaxRequest('/somethingserious/');`
2. При объявлении такого рода переменной, выполняется сама функция
   `artAjaxRequest`, в которой происходит ajax для получения данных json,
   парсится и сохраняется в переменную `artworks`.
3. Далее я хочу использовать `artworks` в функции, которая будет
   присваиваться `getArtsThroughRequest` (через return) и создании
   таким образом через замыкание уникального скопа для переменной
   `artworks`.
4. Пишу `getArtsThroughRequest()` - должен выводиться в консоль объект
   `artworks` (пример, на деле же всё будет сложнее, конечно).

Проблема в том, что при вызове `getArtsThroughRequest()` выводит `undefinded`, а не объект.
Вроде как внутри `xhr.onload обработчика` переменная должна бы быть видна... Или нет? Прошу разъяснить и показать, как исправить ситуацию с видимостью переменной.

Comment: На момент возврата, переменную только инициализировали, значение будет потом. Подробнее - по дубликату.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, дубликат. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: @Other, спасибо.